# import error:ModuleNotFoundError: 'block_model' is not a package

Tags: python, module

im trying to use python open_gl and am making a create object class. Im getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'block_model.py'; 'block_model' is not a package my code is giving the error that i can't fix:
`

```
class Create:
    def __init__(self, cube_x, cube_y, cube_z, file):
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        model = importlib.import_module(file)
        model.verticies()
        model.edges()
        verticies = model.verticies
        edges = model.edges
        for edge in edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
        glEnd()
    c1_x = 0
    c1_y = 0
    c1_z = 0
    print(camera)
cube1 = Create(c1_x, c1_y, c1_z, file="block_model.py")
```

`
and this is what block_model.py looks like:

```
verticies = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1)
)
edges = (
    (0, 1),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7)
)


def verticies():
    # global verticies
    print("Returning verticies")

    return verticies


def edges():
    # global verticies
    print("Returning edges")

    return edges
```

Thanks :)
**EDIT:**i have a new problem it now says:     for edge in edges: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable. anyone have a fix for that?

Comment: Why are you referencing another python file by its file name? Surely you could just use an `import` statement to get want you want from that file?

Comment: so im able to make and use models from other files not just that single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `importlib.import_module`, you don't have to specify ".py".

```
cube1 = Create(c1_x, c1_y, c1_z, file="block_model")
```

Specifically you should pass **module name** ("block_model") as argument, **not file name**. When you pass `"block_model.py"` as argument, the programs is actually interpreting `block_model` as a package name (which, in your case, is non-existent) and `py` as a module in that package. Read this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to know more.